# VivaGraph - How to Export Graph as PNG

Tags: svg, export, png, vivagraphjs

This is a requirement I had to solve so I thought I would post the solution I used for others.

I needed a button that would allow me to save a VivaGraph SVG rendering as PNG.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:
https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng
It worked perfectly for me.

The only file you need is `saveSvgAsPng.js`

If you include that in your html you can call it like so:

```
window.saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("svgID"), "export.png");
```

Wire it up to some handler and when you invoke it you should see export.png as a download.

> NOTE: Your mileage may vary. The author of the github repo said that it may not render everything verbatim for all cases. For my case it rendered a transparent PNG perfectly.
>
> NOTE: Also this doesn't work in IE if that's a requirement for you